# Super constructor in a subclass - Java

Tags: java, class, inheritance, constructor, super

Considering the following code example, can someone help to explain why the result of `B b3= new B (20, 50) ;` `System.out.println(b3)`; is `A:20, B:(10, 61)` ? I thought through calling the `super (x)`, we uses the `A(int x) {this x =x;}` and int x of B has been changed to 20.

PS: I'm looking for the reason behind how it works but not how to print out certain value in B.

```
class A {
  int x;
  A(int x) {
    this.x = x; 
  }
  public String toString() {
     return "A:" + x;
  } 
}
 class B extends A {
   int x = 10;
   int y = x+1;

   B(int x, int y) {
     super(x);
     this.y = this.y + y;
   }
   public String toString() {
     return "A:" + super.x + ", B:(" + x + "," + y + ")";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As many others have meanwhile pointed out, *attributes* are resolved statically in Java, while *methods* are resolved dynamically.  This means that attributes *shadow* while methods *overwrite*.  Casting a variable up to its superclass (as happens implicitly to the `this` pointer) will not affect how methods are resolved but does change how attributes are.

The second thing is that *even if* `A`'s constructor in your example were to assign to `B.x`, it would happen *before* the `B`-part of the object is constructed (as objects are constructed starting with `Object`'s constructor and then walking down the class hierarchy [1]) and the constructor of `B` would overwrite it.  You can verify that the constructor of `A` sees an uninitialized `B` by (only for academic purpose, please) downcasting the `this` pointer in `A`'s constructor and inspecting `B.x`.  It will be 0.

```java
class A {
    int x;
    A(int x) {
        System.out.printf("A() before: A.x = %d%n", this.x);  // 0
        System.out.printf("A() before: B.x = %d%n", (B) this).x);  // 0
        this.x = x;
        System.out.printf("A() after: A.x = %d%n", this.x);  // 7
        System.out.printf("A() after: B.x = %d%n", (B) this).x);  // 0
    }
}

class B extends A {
    int x = 10;
    B() {
        super(7);
        System.out.printf("B(): A.x = %d%n", super.x);  // 7
        System.out.printf("B(): A.x = %d%n", this.x);  // 10
    }
}
```

**Notes:**

1. This might seem illogic: After all, isn't `A`'s constructor *called* from within `B`'s?  It turns out that `super()` is not a normal method invocation but a special feature.

Comment: Thanks! But if say in your example, super(7) in B only changes super.x but not this.x, then how do we use super() constructor to change this.x in this case?

Comment: At the risk of sounding silly: Not at all.  Why do you want to use `super` to change an attribute of your own class.  You can just say `this.x = 7` if so you desire.

Comment: but I thought we use super() to call super class constructor to constructor a subclass object? i.e. B() {super()} will generate a class B object using the constructor in A?

Comment: No, `super()` always calls the base class constructor and it will always construct the base object.  How should creating “a class B object using the constructor in A” possible work?

Comment: By base class, you mean the parent class? so B() {super()} will create an object with int x (as x in parent class A), which means it's a base (parent) object. And after this super(), if we call this.x=7 like you said, will change the x in b, without affecting the previous x we initialized using super() ? Thanks for explaining this and I hope I get it right this time..

Comment: Yes, I think you got it right now.  Any object of type B contains an object (sometimes called sub-object) of type A and `this` in the `super()` constructor refers to that sub-object.  (If you know C, think of it as `struct A { int x; }; struct B { struct A super; int x; }`.)  And yes, base = parent.

Answer (score 1):

Your class `B` is shadowing the `int x` from `A`. If you don't do that,

```
class B extends A {
  // int x = 10; // <-- shadows A.x
  int y = x+1;

  B(int x, int y) {
    super(x);
    this.y = this.y + y;
  }
  public String toString() {
    return "A:" + super.x + ", B:(" + x + "," + y + ")";
  }
}
```

Then your code would work as you expected. Your shadow means there are literally two variables named `x`. To get the parent one you need `super.x` (as you already did).

Comment: I think it is an academic example to demonstrate shadowing.  By using `x` and `super.x` in `B`'s `toString` method correctly, the OP shows to be aware of this.

Comment: @5gon: that seems unclear. if the OP was aware of this i think he wouldn't expect B's x to be changed.

Answer (score 1):

> we uses the A(int x) {this x =x;} and int x of B has been changed to 20.

Actually, no.  It hasn't been *changed* to `20`.  It was never `10` in the first place.

There are two separate `x` instance variables, one declared in `A` and one in `B`.

- In `A (int x) { this.x = x; }`, the `this.x` is the `x` declared in `A`.
- In `class B extends A { int x = 10; ...` the `x` is a different one.

When you assign to one of the `x` variables, it does not alter the other one.  They are *distinct*.

---

What this problem / example is intended to illustrate is *shadowing* ... where one variable in the superclass gets "sort of hidden" by another variable in the subclass.  From a design / coding perspective, it is a bad idea.  You should avoid doing this in *real* code.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you have two `x` variables -- one in `A` and one in `B`, so when you call `super(x)`, it goes to the constructor in `A`, which, because it's in `A`, assigns `A`'s `x` to the argument of `super(x)`. So it sets `super.x` to `20`, but doesn't change the `x` in `B`. So `B`s `x` stays at the `10` it was originally initialized as.

Answer (score 1):

B(int x, int y) constructor has same argument name as instance variable so x pass to super constructor A will be the one which is pass to constructor B and it is not related to instance variable x. Instance variable x(defined as int x=10;) value will be change only when refer by this.x from B's constructor. 'this' keyword used to refer to object that call the function. So no matter what you pass B(any value, y), it will display 10 for x as output as we are not changing value of x.

Does this make sense?

Comment: Thanks! You mean super(x) in b doesn't change b.x?  but I thought it was the way we use super constructor to change b's value